# Incluiding payment systems in a ReactJS/Firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently developing a `ReactJS` & `Firebase` app, but I'm facing the following problem:

As all the code is run in the client side, how can I connect to the payment API without exposing my private token?

I was thinking on creating a `Google Cloud Function` that could handle this requests. I think this functions should manage maybe a sign in to get the token, and later request the payments. Should this work?

Right now `Google Cloud Functions` isn't free to make requests out of a `Google` app. Does someone know how could I avoid the $25/month?

Another alternative I was thinking on was creating a `Rails API` on `Heroku` to manage only this requests, but I'm not sure if I'm not exposing the tokens by managing the logic on the front side. (Because the front end would have to talk to `Firebase` and this new API)

Security is a must.

Thanks!

Comment: do you not have any sort of server for API calls (PHP, Node.JS, Go, .NET, Java)?  Firebase is a service provider of a few products but you still need a server to interact and put data into firebase you're not going client -> db are you?

Comment: My misunderstanding apparently there is a script that allows Firebase to connect directly from client to their hosted db. In that case it's best to save your record into the NoSQL db but do not let users read from it generally you would want the flow to go `client -> server (or some form of communication service) -> payment process` so you're not wrong wanting to use cloud functions, my only suggestion is to create your own server something light like node.JS and have it hosted on digital ocean. It's like $5.00 a month, then you can use that to connect to Firebase & your payment provider.

Comment: yes, you can connect directly to `firebase` from the client side and use their services. The problem isn't the way I store the information in `firebase`, because you could set the rules of the db so anyone could read specific branches. But my worry is when I actually consume the payment API without exposing my private token created dynamically during the payment process...